# vim sub-replace expression with more text

Tags: vim

So I was searching for a way to take something like this

```
Two words
Three Words Here
```

And replace it with this

```
Twowords = myHash["Two words"];
ThreeWordsHere = myHash["Three Words Here"];
```

I found this question, which led me to the sub-replace commands, and I came to something like this.

```
%s/\(\([A-z ]\)\+\)/\=substitute(submatch(1), ' ', '', 'g')/
```

Now this will get the match without spaces to appear, but there will be nothing after the equals sign. Adding in text after the substitute expression results in an "E51: Invalid Expression" error.

My question is: is there a way to end an expression, and add more text to the :s command? Something like this.

```
%s/\(\([A-z ]\)\+\)/\=substitute(submatch(1), ' ', '', 'g') = myHash["\1"];/
```

I have not been able to find anything. I've looked at :help sub-replace-\= and other sources online. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You almost had it.

Everything after an `\=` atom has to be an expression, therefore you need to concatenate strings together and use `submatch()` again.  Using the regex you already provided:

```
:%s/\(\([A-z ]\)\+\)/\=substitute(submatch(1), ' ', '', 'g') . ' = myHash["' . submatch(1) . '"];'/
```

Comment: Your code works, except for the regex (which OP provided). All else being equal, it should start with `:%s/\([A-z ]\+\)/` to get the output he wants based on his sample input. Upvoted!

Comment: I think it still works, it just has an extra group in there that isn't necessary.  Unfortunately I can't test it at the moment.

Comment: Odd, it didn't work for me before, but does now. Sorry for the confusion.